# Proof that covariance of RV and group average is less than variance of RV

Tags: random-variable, covariance, sample, mean

I have a random variable $X_i$ and a group of $N_j$ other random variables that includes $X_i$. Let's just call this group $J$. There are no distributional assumptions made on these RVs (other than having finite first and second moments).

With $\bar{X}_J$ denoting the arithmetic average of all $X_k$ with $k \in J$, how can I prove that $Cov(X_i, \bar{X}_J) \leq Var(X_i)$?

That is, $\bar{X}_J = \frac{1}{N_j}\sum_{k\in J}X_k.$ To be clear, $X_i$ is one of these random variables in group $J$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $N=2$, $Var(X_1) = 1,$  $Var(X_2) = 10$, $Cov(X_1,X_2) =3$.

Then $Cov(X_1,\bar X) = Cov(X_1, \frac 12 X_1 + \frac 12 X_2) = 2 \gt 1 = Var(X_1)$

So $Cov(X_i, \bar{X}_J) \leq Var(X_i)$ has problem.